# Jinja2 templating - comparing strings

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

```
"{{ 'a+rwx' if '{{ item }}' == '{{ airflow_dag_folder }}' else 'u+rwx,g+rx,o+rx' }}"
```

This is what I'd like to compare, but it always returns u+rwx,g+rx,o+rx. Want it to return a+rwx when they match but even when item is the same as airflow_dag_folder it won't return the right thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a Jinja2 expression. Variables in Jinja2 expressions are referred by their names (and without quotes).

In your expression, you are comparing a string `{{ item }}` with a string `{{ airflow_dag_folder }}`. These two strings are not equal, so you always get the value defined in else-statement.

Instead use:

```
"{{ 'a+rwx' if item == airflow_dag_folder else 'u+rwx,g+rx,o+rx' }}"
```